# wand.image gives the error when I try to access

Tags: python, installation, imagemagick, wand

```
from wand.image import Image
```

Gives the following error:
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
When I installed ImageMagick, I still got the same error.

Comment: Did you install Imagemagick 7 or Imagemagick 6? Perhaps Wand is only be compatible with Imagemagick 6. Did you re-install Wand after you installed Imagemagick?

Comment: first I install ImageMagick-7 after that I install ImageMagick-6

Comment: I have ImageMagick 6.9.10-6 Q16 x64. and python 3.6.5 <'32bit', 'WindowsPE'>

Comment: I manage mine previous error but i got new error :with Image(filename="scansmpl.pdf[0]", resolution=300) as img:  TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: Either the PDF could not be read, or ghostscript is not installed.